# TensorFlow in R Studio: RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0x10 but this version of numpy is 0xe

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, rstudio

I am trying to get started with TensorFlow, specifically in RStudio. I have followed many different tutorials, and keep running into an error when I run

```
library(tensorflow)
install_tensorflow(envname = "r-reticulate")
```

this is the output:

```
> RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0x10 but this
> version of numpy is 0xe
> 
> RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0x10 but this
> version of numpy is 0xe
> 
> ImportError: numpy.core._multiarray_umath failed to import
> 
> ImportError: numpy.core.umath failed to import
```

My pip and conda numpy versions are the same, and I cannot seem to get to the bottom of this. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!